# remove workspace from title in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have recently moved to another computer and the name of this computer is long and in all caps.  I usually have 2-3 sessions open and it gets confusing since the workspace name is my computer name, it takes up the majority of the tab on the start bar as you can see below.

[image]

Is there a way to change what shows in the title bar so I don't have to play a guessing game as to which one is the solution I need to work on?

I checked the settings but there are so many I probably overlooked it. At least, I hope so :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two extension available to change Visual Studio window title: [Visual Studio Window Title Changer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e8ebfe4-023f-4c4d-9b7a-d05bbc5cb239) and [Rename Visual Studio Window Title](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f3f23845-5b1e-4811-882f-60b7181fa6d6).

Comment: Ah an extension,  I was thinking it was a setting somewhere. Tyvm!!